# How can I prevent gui freezing in wxpython?

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

**[PROBLEM]**
If I click on a button that triggers a function then gui will freeze until the function concludes.

**[CODE]**

```
import wx
app = wx.App(redirect=False)
top = wx.Frame(None)
top.Maximize(True) # Set to maximize the application
sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()

def testFunction(event):
    import pyautogui
    import time
    pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
    for i in range(2):
            pyautogui.hotkey('win','r')
            time.sleep (0.5)
            pyautogui.typewrite('cmd.exe')
            time.sleep (0.5)
            pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
            time.sleep (0.5)
            time.sleep (3)


addButton = wx.Button( top, -1, "Start", style=wx.BU_EXACTFIT )
sizer.Add(addButton, (6, 8), (2, 14), wx.EXPAND)
top.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, testFunction, addButton)
top.Sizer = sizer
top.Sizer.Fit(top)
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[CURRENT]
The gui freezes until the function ends.

[DESIRED]
The gui should not freeze.
Note: I think that is related to threads but I cannot quite grasp this concept.

Comment: Use threads. Here you have an example for adding them to the GUI in wxPython: http://wiki.wxpython.org/Non-Blocking%20Gui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this worked for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx
app = wx.App(redirect=False)
top = wx.Frame(None)
top.Maximize(False) # Set to maximize the application
sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()

def testFunction(event):
    import time
    for i in range(2):
        print ('win','r')
        time.sleep (0.5)
        print ('cmd.exe')
        time.sleep (0.5)
        print ('enter')
        time.sleep (0.5)
        print 'sleep'
        time.sleep (3)
        print u"Iteración %d".format(i+1)

def thread_start(event):
    import threading
    th = threading.Thread(target=testFunction, args=(event,))
    th.start()



addButton = wx.Button( top, -1, "Start", style=wx.BU_EXACTFIT )
sizer.Add(addButton, (6, 8), (2, 14), wx.EXPAND)
# top.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, testFunction, addButton)
top.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, thread_start, addButton)
top.Sizer = sizer
top.Sizer.Fit(top)
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

You have a non-blicking gui.
You could start with that and add input variables (like getting and identification to your thread so you can tell which thread is being called).

I removed the py2autogui library because I don't have it installed (and isn't necessary to the example).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`wx.CallLater`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.CallLater-class.html) which will call given callable with argument after given time. The structure of the function `testFunction` should be change:

```
def testFunction(event):
    import pyautogui
    pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

    def step1(i):
        pyautogui.hotkey('win','r')
        wx.CallLater(500, step2, i)
    def step2(i):
        pyautogui.typewrite('cmd.exe')
        wx.CallLater(500, step3, i)
    def step3(i):
        pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
        if i <= 1:
            return
        wx.CallLater(3500, step1, i-1)

    step1(2)
```

Comment: This doesn't really unblock the GUI you're just replacing the `time.sleep` (which could be a simulation of some calculation) with that `CallLater` function, isn't it?

Comment: @tglaria, By calling `wx.CAllLater`, the control is passed to event loop.

Comment: but it doesn't keep the function running, it sounds like a thread with a delayed starts, isn't it? Re-reading the question, it works for this application, but it shouldn't be a generic answer for non-blocking GUI, right?

Comment: @tglaria, You should be careful when using thread in GUI program. Doing gui stuffs in non gui thread could cause problem.

Answer (score -1):

I am not that familiar with wx but mabye this helps

```
import wx
import threading
app = wx.App(redirect=False)
top = wx.Frame(None)
top.Maximize(True) # Set to maximize the application
sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()

def testFunction(event):
    import pyautogui
    import time
    pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
    for i in range(2):
            pyautogui.hotkey('win','r')
            time.sleep (0.5)
            pyautogui.typewrite('cmd.exe')
            time.sleep (0.5)
            pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
            time.sleep (0.5)
            time.sleep (3)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=testFunction, args=[])    

addButton = wx.Button( top, -1, "Start", style=wx.BU_EXACTFIT )
sizer.Add(addButton, (6, 8), (2, 14), wx.EXPAND)
top.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, t1, addButton)
top.Sizer = sizer
top.Sizer.Fit(top)
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you're linking a thread to an event, but when does this thread start? And once the threads ends, you have to recreate it (which isn't done in here)

Comment: @tglaria. yes. I read that article, in the same time I did not quite understand, that;s the reason why I asked for a hint to get me started. I will dig some more .....